# Boyce codd normal form

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

I have the following relationship:

R(W, X, Y, Z)

X->Y

X->Z

I have to decompose it into BCNF. I don't understand how I'm supposed to go about doing this as I have no information about W.

I've been searching online for the past 2 hours trying to find a resource that explains this simply. Just don't get it.

Comment: This looks like homework, and I'd like to give you a hint rather than provide you the answer, but that doesn't seem easy. Anyhow, here's the answer and if you want to really understand why this makes sense you have to think of a real-life example, e.g. X is customer ID, Y and Z are customer phone and address and Ws are dependent IDs

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems pretty simple to me, you get 2 relations:

- R1(X, Y, Z) where X is the PK
- R2(X, W) where X+W is the PK

Comment: Are you sure you don't need R1A(X, Y) and R1B(X, Z)?  I agree with R2.

Comment: You only need R1A and R1B is both of them are sub-types of a supertype R1(X), which isn't currently mentioned in the problem, so I'd assume they are not needed